# Is there any difference between "2 instances of JVM" and "2 different JVMs"?

Tags: java, jvm

I have been told to make an EJB and plain Java program (client), and try to run both these in two different JVMs, and get them executed. What is meant by "two different JVMs"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your requirement :

1. EJB
2. Plain Java client for (1)

Run in different JVMs - it is as simple as it can get.

Normally EJBs are hosted in an Application server ( Such as Weblogic,Websphere, Jboss,Glassfish, etc etc) - when you deploy your EJB to one such server and start that server - server process is a "JVM"- meaning your server process that hosts your EJB is running in a JVM.

Now, you have written and compiled your Client application. For laughs, let us call it 
`MyBigClient.java`

when you run `java MyBigClient` on command line or run it through the "Run" button of your favorite IDE, it is executed by a JVM - that is your second JVM instance

Voila - you have EJB and Client running in *two different* JVMs

Now if you use a different "java.exe"(Say, C:\JDK1.6\bin\java.exe) to run the client than the java.exe (Say, C:\JDK1.5\bin\java.exe) used by your application server, you are using "two different JVMs"

It is all how you want to define "two different" - I do not think there is any hard and fast rule around this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using NetBeans IDE. I am creating New Project-> Enterprise application project , in which I have my EJB, and then I am creating New Project-> Enterprise Application client, So can we say my EJB and client are running in differnt JVM?

Comment: @RohitElayathu - Just by creating EJB - you are not "running" it.You need to deploy it to an application server (like the Glassfish that comes with NB) - which in turn will spawn its own JVM when started.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I can't discern a difference between the two.  For the record, two *different* JVMs would be, in my mind, two JVMs with different versions (JRE 6 and JRE 7), and two *instances* implies that it's one JVM version being used twice (i.e. two separate Java applications).

Comment: ok. then how can I create EJB and  JAVA program(client) in diffrent JVM , in my single system.

Answer (score 0):

Set your class path to one JVM for the EJB; Set the class path to another JVM for the client.